# Screensaver not working at all, Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS

Tags: 16.04, gnome, lock-screen, screensaver

Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS, Gnome classic desktop, libgnome2-comm 2.32.1-5ubun.
The screensaver not working at all: when power supply connected to laptop, and laptop stay idle, display newer turn off, and screensaver never appears.
When I use Debian jessie booted from external USB drive, its default screensaver works excellent, clever algorithm, no needs for any adjusting whatsoever.
How to adjust Ubuntu screensaver, or, better, to install same screensaver as have Debian jessie?

Comment: just fyi: The GNOME desktop on 16.04 is EOL, only Unity 7, Kylin and server (no desktop) still get updates/upgrades; the 3 years for flavors have passed, so consider upgrading to 18.04 LTS if you want to use GNOME (gnome gets the full 5 years as it's the default desktop for 18.04).

Comment: Debian old-old-stable (jessie) uses xscreensaver 5.30 which is older than that used by Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (5.34 https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=xscreensaver), so just disable gnome-screensaver and enable and use xscreensaver.

Comment: End of life does not mean applications may not work or work incorrectly. How I can adjust gnome-screensaver settings?

Comment: What need be adusted to make the Gnome screensaver runs a random graphics demo when the keyboard and mouse have been idle for a period? (just standard behaviour).

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/665176/how-to-set-up-gnome-screensaver provides a few details, but gnome-screensaver is basic (it's primary purpose was to blank & screen lock).  Most use xscreensaver if they want more than just blanking & locking features.

Comment: xscreensaver 5.30 is for debian jessie (2015); being an older version than Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (2016-April release) uses.  This site supports only Ubuntu (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: OK. I uninstalled gnome-screensaver and installed xscreensaver via Ubuntu Software Center: it works, but seems not always start when it should (after 10 min idle time). Can't figure out how to adjust this.